# Java JDBC bugs with transaction and losing data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, transactions

I have 2 bugs rarely happening during last 3 years.

If I have 100 orders during a day 1-2 orders have alerts when manual db check says that number was not incremented, !! but when i check db manually it is really incremented.

If I have 3000 orders during a month 3-5 orders have alerts when lock is not released from order after order completion. But when I check db manually it is not null when it should be null

I am using only jdbcTemplate and transactional template(select, update, read). I am using JPA only when insert a model to mysql.

Everything is done with lock by 1 thread.

Code snippet to show the issue:

```
public synchronized void test() {
    long payment = 999;
    long bought_times_before = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select bought_times from user where id = ?", new Object[]{1}, Long.class);
    TransactionTemplate tmpl = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
    tmpl.setTimeout(300);
    tmpl.setName("p:" + payment);
    tmpl.executeWithoutResult(status -> {
        jdbcTemplate.update("update orders set  attempts_to_verify = attempts_to_verify + 1, transaction_value = null where id = ?", payment);
        jdbcTemplate.update("update orders set  locked = null where id = ?", payment);
        jdbcTemplate.update("update user set bought_times = bought_times + 1 where id = 1");
    });
    long bought_times_after = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select bought_times from user where id = ?", new Object[]{1}, Long.class);
    if (bought_times_after <= bought_times_before) log.error("bought_times_after <= bought_times_before");
}
```

I upgraded mysql and implemented redis distributed lock to allow only 1 thread run code with select and transaction and select.

UPDATE:
default isolation level is read comited
i tried serializable but it still has the same bug

UPDATE 2:
re: lock != null after transaction it is somehow related to high load on mysql, since it is never occur when low load.

UPDATE 3:
i checked mysql logs - nothing, no errors
also i tried to use REQUIRED_NEW + SERIALIZABLE but received dead locks

UPDATE 4:

i wrote a test and cannot reproduce the issue - but on production there are more than 1 transaction as well as more updates and reads but i guess it is hardware issue or mysql bug

```
    @PostConstruct
public void test(){
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST ( id int, name int, locked boolean )");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into TEST values(1, 1, 1);");

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        long prev = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select name from TEST where id = 1", Long.class);
        TransactionTemplate tmpl = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
        jdbcTemplate.update("update TEST set locked = true  where id = 1;");

        tmpl.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus status) {
                jdbcTemplate.update("update TEST set name = name + 1 where id = 1;");
                jdbcTemplate.update("update TEST set locked = false  where id = 1;");
            }
        });
        long curr = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select name from TEST where id = 1", Long.class);
        boolean lock = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select locked from TEST where id = 1", Boolean.class);
        if(curr <= prev){
            log.error("curr <= prev");
        }
        if(lock){
            log.error("lock = true");
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE 5: WAS ABLE TO REPRODUCE IT!!!!

```
    @PostConstruct
public void test(){
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST ( id int, name int, locked boolean )");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into TEST values(1, 1, 1);");
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            RLock rLock = redissonClient.getFairLock("lock");
            try {
                rLock.lock(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                long prev = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select name from TEST where id = 1", Long.class);
                TransactionTemplate tmpl = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
                jdbcTemplate.update("update TEST set locked = true  where id = 1;");
                tmpl.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                    @SneakyThrows
                    @Override
                    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus status) {
                        jdbcTemplate.update("update TEST set name = name + 1 where id = 1;");
                        jdbcTemplate.update("update TEST set locked = false  where id = 1;");
                    }
                });
                long curr = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select name from TEST where id = 1", Long.class);
                boolean lock = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select locked from TEST where id = 1", Boolean.class);
                if (curr <= prev) {
                    log.error("curr <= prev");
                }
                if (lock) {
                    log.error("lock = true");
                }
            } finally {
                rLock.unlock();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

UPDATE 7: after the second and third run i cannot reproduce it again neither with Lock nor with FairLock ..

UPDATE 8: on prod i am using 3 redis lock with 120 sec timeouts so i think there is timeout occurs rarely on 1 of 3 lock thus code might be executed by 2 threads without lock

**SOLUTION: increase lock timeout as well as transaction timeout up to 500 seconds**

UPDATE 9: looks like the issue has been resolved but i need to monitor it during couple of weeks before close the issue on stack overflow

Comment: What transaction isolation level is this transaction set to? If the answer isn't "serializable", this is probably behaving according to spec.

Comment: default transaction level is read comited

Comment: you may want to read up on what these mean. You probably want serializable.

Comment: @zelenb Post such details as edits to the Question rather than as a Comment. Also, be careful about spelling, for [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

Comment: serializable did not solve the issue. wrong number still occurs presumable chance of bug is 1% (1-2 times per day ... )

Comment: i am even do not know what should i hate either spring or mysql. 
do not know on which side the bug is

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: unfortunately  no i cannot reproduce it but on production it happens rarely 
i hope it is hardware issue or rare mysql bug

Comment: locks like redis lock timeout the root cause ...